# Closure of Graph of Equivalence Relation

Tags: general-topology, symplectic-geometry

I am reading McDuff and Salamon's "J-holomorphic curves and symplectic topology". I am stuck at a (probably trivial) point. On page 32 of the book, the authors take an equivalence relation $\Gamma_0$ on $\Sigma\setminus X$ (where $\Sigma$ is a compact Riemann surface and $X$ a finite subset of it), thought of as a subset of $\Sigma\setminus X\times\Sigma\setminus X$ and consider its closure $\Gamma$ in $\Sigma\times\Sigma$. It is known that $\Gamma_0$ is closed in $\Sigma\setminus X\times\Sigma\setminus X$ and that $\Gamma\setminus\Gamma_0\subseteq X\times X$. They then claim that $\Gamma$ is the graph of an equivalence relation on $\Sigma$. I'm able to see that $\Gamma$ is reflexive and symmetric. I'm not able to see why transitivity of $\Gamma$ is true. I'm not sure of how much of the preceding part of the proof (on page 31) is necessary for the proof of this assertion.

In summary, can someone help me see that $\Gamma$ is indeed transitive?

Comment: Have you considered convergent sequences? If $(x,y) \in \Gamma$ and $(y, z) \in \Gamma$ then there are sequences $(x_k, y_k) \in \Gamma_0$ and $(y_k, z_k) \in \Gamma_0$ such that $(x_k, y_k) \to (x, y)$ and $(y_k, z_k) \to (y, z)$. Does $(x_k, z_k) \to (x, z)$? If so, then $(x, z) \in \Gamma$.

Comment: @md2perpe: Why can we choose the sequences converging to $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ such that they have the same $y_n$-coordinate?

Comment: Good question. Take them different, i.e. $\Gamma_0 \ni y'_k \to y$ and $\Gamma_0 \ni y''_k \to y$. Then we have $x_k \Gamma_0 y'_k \Gamma_0 y''_k \Gamma_0 z_k$, so $x_k \Gamma_0 z_k$ with $x_k \to x$ and $z_k \to z$, i.e. $(x_k, z_k) \to (x, z)$, so $(x, z) \in \Gamma$.

Comment: @md2perpe: I'm sorry but I don't see why $y'_k\Gamma_0y''_k$. Could you please explain?

Comment: Hm... I need to stop answering without thinking. Now I have something to think about during the day.

Comment: Just before I left work I realized that we actually can take $y'_k = y''_k$  thanks to $\Sigma$ being a continuum and $X$ being sparse. In the bus home I refined my arguments and will write a full answer.

Comment: By the way, isn't it just to take sequences $x_k \to x$, $y_k \to y$, $z_k \to z$ with $x_k, y_k, z_k \in \Gamma_0$?

Comment: @md2perpe: Could you please write a full answer? I'm still not able to see why we can take $y'_k = y''_k$.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like I was wrong again. I thought of all of $(\Sigma \setminus X) \times (\Sigma \setminus X)$ as $\Gamma_0$.

Comment: A related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283230/when-is-the-topological-closure-of-an-equivalence-relation-automatically-an-equi?rq=1